# Is this possible in this command to cd into the directory thats printed in output

Tags: linux, bash, directory, grep, ls

When I do `ls | grep -e *-folder1` it prints `my-folder1` that's the name of the folder matched in the command in current directory.

Is there a way I can add something like cd into this directory. This is more of an attempt to learn Bash or commands on Linux, rather than about doing what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why bothering with `grep` if you know that the glob-pattern is unique? You can simply do a `cd *-folder1`. If there is more than one matching folder, you will get an error message.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```bash
ls | grep -- -folder1 | while read -r dir
do
    cd "$dir"
    # do things in $dir
done
# do things in the original directory
```

but parsing the output of `ls` is [not recommended](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead). You could instead use globbing:

```bash
for dir in *-efolder*
do
    cd "$dir"
    # do things in $dir
    cd .. # need to back out again
done
# do things in the original directory
```

---

If the purpose isn't to `grep` on all folders matching a certain pattern and to `cd` down into each one of them, but to simply `cd` into a directory ending with `-folder1`, then:

```bash
cd *-folder1
```

If you get zero or multiple hits, `cd` will shown an error.